# Multiple parameters url laravel

Tags: laravel-4

Someone has been given for having to pass multiple arguments to form the url. I mean miweb.com / (sale) / (city) / (product) / (foo) where each () is dynamic ie load tables database. I searched google and stackoverflow but I have not found anything that has become clear to me as this level routes and drivers. Someone had to do? I could explain or tell where can I find it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to generate an url with this route or get variables from this route in your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work of loading tables is not done by your routes, but your controller:

```
Route::get('/{sale}/{city}/{product}/{foo}', function($sale, $city, $product, $foo)
{
    $saleModel = Sale::find($sale);
    $cityModel = City::find($city);

    ...

    return $cityModel->name;
});
```

So when you hit:

```
http://miweb.com/1/rio/computer/bar
```

It will hit that route and do what your controller (in this case is a closure) tells it to do.

Comment: that is clear, the question is that if I do as you propose. Are not too many queries to the database? If I say 5 parameters as would suit 5 queries, right?

Comment: It all depends on your database schema and what you need to accomplish, 5 parameters may become just one query with some AND to glue them.